# How to include and use text field in installer

Tags: textbox, nsis

I would like to include license-check into my NSIS installer. Simple Text field and button would be enough for me, but I didn't find any example how to include Text field (text box) into page and how to read its value.

Will you help me with it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to create a text field :

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
...
Var EDIT
...
${NSD_CreateText} 0 35 100% 12u SomeDefaultText
Pop $EDIT
```

And get the input (Not sure for this one) :

```
System::Call user32::GetWindowText(i$EDIT,t.r0,i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})
```

(As show in example\nsDialogs\example.nsi)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and found a different solution:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

...

Page custom MyPageFunc MyPageFuncLeave

...

Var txt
Var myTextBox

...

Function MyPageFunc
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 50u 10u "Username:"
    ${NSD_CreateText} 70 0 100u 12u ""
    Pop $myTextBox
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageFuncLeave
    ${NSD_GetText} $myTextBox $txt
FunctionEnd
```

Later pages and their function then have access to $txt, which has the text from the textbox.